# AWS Lambda always return 502 bad gateway using callback node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, knex.js

I have created an api which uses knex, creates an excel file and upload it to s3 and returns a url, this is working fine in serverless offline but won't work on lambda.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    knex.select(
        'Id',
        'Name'
    ).from(AREA)
        .then(async function (rows) {
            url = await exportExcel(rows); // this returns a URL which should be returned back
            res = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: url
            };
            console.log(res);  // this prints correct url in res
            callback(null, res); // callback is called with res which contains url in body
        })
};
```

The error I got

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: Try to log the exception that your handler is throwing. Though 502 sounds like server is not even running. Try to create first a simple handler that returns a static string and only if that is working try to do something more complicated.

Comment: Could you put the knex select into a try/catch and log out the error it throws? Should give a little bit more insights I guess.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö server is running and returning strings

Comment: @tpschmidt tried using try/catch. It didn't throw any error

Comment: @ShubhamSharma good, next you just need to write your code incrementally and verify after each step that it still works as expected.